# Uploading an image file from camera or gallery to a node.js rest service from ionic2

Tags: javascript, file-upload, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have been trying to upload an image to my node.js rest service (implemented using multer) from my Ionic 2 app.

I am calling the below upload pic method passing the image local file path and an additional parameter that I pass to the node service.

I am able to see the file data in chrome dev tools but the onreadystatechange never seems to get triggered.

I am using ionic 2 beta 2.0.0.17. Any help much appreciated.

```
uploadPic(personid,imageData) {
    var fileStream = null;
    var self = this.resource;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageData,
            (fileDetail) => {
                fileDetail.file(function(file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                    }

                    fileStream = reader.result;
                    var formdata=new FormData();
                    formdata.append("upload", fileStream, "help.png");
                    formdata.append('filename', personid + '.png');
                    formdata.append('personId', personid);
                    let xhr:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('POST', self.api_url + self.method_persons + '/photo', true);

                    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                            } else {
                                reject(xhr.response);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    xhr.setRequestHeader('hpApp-Token', self.entity_token);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ self.usr_token);
                    xhr.send(formdata);
                });
            },
            (err)=> {
                console.log("read error",err)
            });
    });
```